# How to filter Haystack SearchQuerySets by related models

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

How do you filter/join a Haystack SearchQuerySet by related model fields?

I have a query like:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(models.Person)
```

and this returns the same results that the equivalent admin page returns.

However, if I try and filter by model records linked by a foreign key:

```
sqs = sqs.filter(workplace__role__name='teacher')
```

it returns nothing, even though the page `/admin/myapp/person/?workplace__role__name=teacher` returns several records.

I don't want to do any full-text searching of these related models. I only want to do a simple exact-match filter. Is that possible with Haystack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot perform joins using a search engine like the ones supported by haystack.
To make queries like this you need to add the information you want to filter on in a "denormalized" fashion in your search index:

```
class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    # your other fields, most likely model attributes
    role_name = indexes.CharField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Person

    def prepare_role_name(self, person):
        return person.workplace.role_name
```

Then you can filter on a field `role_name`. Just make sure to update your index if eg. the name changes, then you have to update all the according entries in the search index.

Comment: Your specific example doesn't make sense, as the person->workplace link is a one to many relation.

Comment: Well that's the way these search engines work... On the other hand accessing this denormalized information is superfast because you don't need to do any further lookups/joins to access it. If you avoid hitting your database when displaying the search results you can have a big performance advantage... Also see this http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/best_practices.html#avoid-hitting-the-database

Comment: Don't know your exact data layout... You could do the same as above with a one to many relationship, using haystack's `MultiValueField` which can hold a list (and that you can filter for single values). See this gist https://gist.github.com/cooncesean/2892533

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    # your other fields, most likely model attributes
    role_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='workplace__role__name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Person
```

And you can filter by role_name.
I saw it here. http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html